# How to pre-assign arguments to multiprocesses in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python program which employs multiprocessing. The code which i am using for it is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

p = mp.Pool(processes=10)
return_something = p.starmap(myfunc, argumentpool)
p.close()
p.join()
```

The argument pool contains about 100 arguments say from 1 to 100.
So each process gets 10 arguments to process.

I want to pre-assign which all arguments get processed by which multiprocess. For eg.

Process-1 gets argument nos (1, 8, 13, 34, 45, 52, 73, 89, 95, 97)

Process-2 gets argument nos (5, 7, 18, ...)

and so on.

Is there even a way to pre-assign arguments to multiprocesses in python?

Comment: Partition the arguments. Create a closure for each of the processes binding the arguments to them.

Comment: `@rdas` Can you please elaborate with code?

Comment: The way your question is posed, it sounds like you care which physical process number gets to process a certain call. If that is not the case, clarify. If it is the case, why?

Comment: `@Booboo` My requirement is a part of a bigger one. So yes I do need to pre define which arguments are processed by which physical process. Because as of now the arguments are getting randomly fetched by the processes. So what can be the most efficient way to pre assign the arguments to processes?